# Use sed to retrieve IP address from one string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have one variable

```
my_var=Hello 192.168.0.1:22 World
```

I want to retrieve this IP from variable, I write sed command as

```
echo $my_var | sed -n "s/.*\([0-9\.]\+\):.*$/\1/p"
```

I expect get `"192.168.0.1"` as return. Instead, I got return as `"1"`

Could someone help me? What is wrong with my sed

Comment: As no one has pointed it out, none of the solutions will work as my_var only has the string 'Hello' in it and prior to that the line will error with something like :- 192.168.0.1:22: command not found.  So you might want to fix this issue before proceeding with any attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.*` is greedy, so it will match the numbers in the IP. You need to make it stop at the space before the IP.

```
echo $my_var | sed -n "s/.* \([0-9.]\+\):.*$/\1/p"
```

If `sed` supported PCRE, you could use a non-greedy quantifier `.*?`, but it only has BRE and ERE.

If there isn't always a space, you could match any non-number. But you also need to allow for the IP to be at the beginning of the string.

```
echo $my_var | sed -n "s/^\(\|.*[^0-9]\)\([0-9.]\+\):.*$/\2/p"
```

BTW, it's not necessary to escape `.` inside `[]`.

Comment: I run command echo $my_var | sed -n "s/^\(\|.*[^0-9]\)\([0-9.]\+\):.*$/\2/p", it returns still as "1"

Comment: You are right I'm greedy with ".*" This gives me what I want. #######echo $my_var | sed -n "s/[^0-9]*\([0-9\.]\+\):.*$/\1/p"#######. Thank you!

Comment: That won't work if there are numbers before the IP, e.g. `my_var="123hello 192.168.0.1:22"`

Answer (score 0):

With [bash parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
$ r='Hello 192.168.0.1:22 World'
$ # remove upto first space
$ echo "${r#* }"
192.168.0.1:22 World
$ s="${r#* }"
$ # remove from first : to end of line
$ echo "${s%%:*}"
192.168.0.1
```

With `awk`

```
$ # space or : is input delimiter
$ echo "$r" | awk -F'[ :]' '{print $2}'
192.168.0.1
```